# Is there a way to serialize certain properties that are not property of the base class? using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, json.net

I want to serialize this class properties(only IsSuccess,StatusCode,Description,Messages)
But Newtonsoft serialized all properties base and BaseException properties

```
public class BaseException :  Exception
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Messages { get; set; }
    public BaseException(int statusCode, string message, string description)
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        IsSuccess = false;
        Description = description;
        Messages = message;
    }
    public BaseException()
    {

    }

}
```

serialize method that i used in exception middleware

```
    private string ConvertJsonData(Exception e, int statusCode)
    {
        string json="";
        var type = e.GetType();
        if (e.GetType() == typeof(BaseException))
        {
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new BaseException
            {
                IsSuccess = (bool)type.GetProperty("IsSuccess").GetValue(e),
                StatusCode = statusCode,
                Messages = (string)type.GetProperty("Messages").GetValue(e),
                Description = (string)type.GetProperty("Description").GetValue(e),
                
            });
        }
        return json;
    }
```

I throw BaseException:

```
throw new BaseException(404, "Not Found", "Kullanıcı Bulunamadı");
```

json response from controller :

```
{
  "StatusCode": 404,
  "IsSuccess": false,
  "Messages": "Not Found",
  "Description": "Kullanıcı Bulunamadı",
  "StackTrace": null,
  "Message": "Exception of type 'SharedNote.Application.Exceptions.BaseException' was thrown.",
  "Data": {},
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpLink": null,
  "Source": null,
  "HResult": -2146233088
}
```

Comment: Instead of serializing an exception, why not create a POCO-class that you serialize instead that contains only those four properties but does not inherit the exception?

Comment: ı can make this way you say. I wonder if this build is bad for you and BaseException is not serializable as i want. Also, I thought that I could manage everything from a single class.

Comment: you're essentially mixing two different concerns here: one being *data* which is ment to be **passed around**, and one is *error-handling*, which is **throwing something**.

Comment: you say throw an exception, then catch it and replace the data in it with poco class and then serialize the poco class and return as response. Did I get right?

Comment: Eeeeh, no, within your `ConvertJsonData`-method you can simply create the POCO--instance from the provided exception-instance and serilize the former.

Comment: okey,  I will use the BaseException class and I created a poco object to serialize the 4 properties I want more easily and I serialized it. The data came as I requested, thank you.
Just because of the title I'm wondering, can we serialize the base class without Exception class properties as I asked in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Json opt-in serialization attribute and specify with JsonProperty properties that should be serialized.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class BaseException :  Exception
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Messages { get; set; }

       .... another properties

}
```

test

```
var ex= new BaseException(404,"message","description");
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

result

```
{
  "IsSuccess": false,
  "StatusCode": 404,
  "Description": "description",
  "Messages": "message"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially mixing two different concerns here. An exception is just something that indicates an error and that is ment to be thrown to some error-handler. It does not really have any data despite its message and maybe an error-code or something similar. In particular it won't have something called `IsSuccess`.

The other thing here is **data**, which you just pass around, but that itself has no meaning. So you should seperate those two concerns here by either not inheriting `Exception` in the first place, or by creating some data-exchange-class with those four properties:

```
class MyExchangeClass // does NOT inherit Exception
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Now it's easy to serialize that one. Just wrap your exception into that exchange-class:

```
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyExchangeClass { IsSuccess = ... });
```